# How to remove http URL links from a data frame column in nlp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, data-cleaning

I have a data frame that has a column with text data in it. I want to remove all the URL links from the text data. 
For eg, the df column looks similar to this-

```
user_id      post_title
    1        #hello....world!!https://www.facebook.com
    2        https://www.google.com
    3        https://www.facebook.com
```

I tried doing this but I get an error 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. How to fix this?

```
def replaceURL(post_title):
   post_title = post_title.map(lambda x: re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))','',str(x)))
    post_title = post_title.str.strip()
    post_title = post_title.map(lambda x: re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1','',str(x)))
    return post_title
```

```
df['post_title'] = replaceURL(df['post_title'])
df['post_title_length'] = df['post_title'].str.len()
df
```

The output should be blank values in place of URL links:

```
user_id      post_title
    1        #hello....world!!
    2        
    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas [str.extract](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html#pandas-series-str-extract),

```
df1['post_title'] = df1['post_title'].str.extract('(.*)http?')

    user_id post_title
0   1       #hello....world!!
1   2   
2   3
```

Note: if you might possibly have text after the URL, I would go for two capture groups and combine them.
eg:

```
    user_id post_title
0   1       #hello....world!!https://www.facebook.com
1   2       https://www.google.com
2   3       https://www.facebook.com
3   4       https://facebook.com Hello world


df1['post_title'] = df1['post_title'].str.extract('(.*)http?.*.com?(.*)?').sum(1)
```

You get

```
    user_id post_title
0   1       #hello....world!!
1   2   
2   3   
3   4       Hello world
```

Edit: Here is a new sample df with http and https links ,

```
    user_id post_title
0   1   #hello....world!!https://www.facebook.com
1   2   https://www.google.com
2   3   https://www.facebook.com
3   4   https://facebook.com Hello world
4   5   #hello....world!!http://www.facebook.com


df1['post_title'].str.replace('http.*.com', '',regex = True)
```

Output,

```
0    #hello....world!!
1                     
2                     
3          Hello world
4    #hello....world!!
```

Comment: 90k is not that big. Try replace instead. df1['post_title'] = df1['post_title'].str.replace('http.*.com', '',regex = True)

Comment: Doesn't work as in the kernel hangs or the code doesn't work?

Comment: @Vaishali.....The code doesn't work properly.
The below code works but just for https links not the http. Can you tell me how to modify this code to remove both?
df['cleanTitle'] = df['post_title'].apply(lambda x: re.split('https:\/\/.*', str(x))[0])

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190940/discussion-between-user11035754-and-vaishali).